# Why Firebase Datasnapshot return null value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 DatabaseReference d1_dr = databaseReference.child("D1");
    d1_dr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                tt_subjectList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){

                    Model_tt_subject model_tt_subject = ds.getValue(Model_tt_subject.class);

                    tt_subjectList.add(model_tt_subject);
                    adapter_tt_sub =  new Adapter_tt_sub(getApplicationContext(),tt_subjectList);
                    d1_recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter_tt_sub);

                }


            }

        }
```

This is debugging result, there is a value in "1" but the snapshot returns a null value, I don't know why

[image]

I want to get data from firebase reference "D1" in my Model_tt_subject class. There is a value inside the database reference but snapshot returns a null value.

Comment: It looks like no data exists at `databaseReference.child("D1")`. If you think there is, please edit your question to show: 1) how `databaseReference` is initialized, 2) the data from `databaseReference` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add to your question what Frank van Puffelen asked for and responded with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  there is *D1> 1> subject* and subject value is "something". I want that value of the subject through creating a Model class. I used Model class because there are 1,2,3,4,5 nodes(child) in D1 and every child of D1 has a subject and I want to store all child subject values in a list. If you don't get me please contact me at neerajdhurandar@gmail.com

Comment: Don't describe the JSON, but instead show the actual, exact JSON with which the problem occurs. I showed you how to get that in my first comment, and you can add it to your question by clicking the `edit` link under your question.